# SQL WHERE is number or null

Tags: sql, join

I am trying to write a sql query that should allow a specified number and/or NULL value within a WHERE clause. Here is what I have written so far:

```
SELECT * 
FROM sd_menus a
LEFT JOIN sd_menu_items b
ON b.id_menu = a.id
LEFT JOIN `sd_menu_items_value_lang` c
ON c.item_id = b.id
WHERE a.name = 'mainNav'
AND (lang_id = 2 OR lang_id = NULL)
```

I think that the reason the above is not working, is because of the OR statement, and that in this case I need And/Or. I guess you can do that with SQL, but how? :)

Comment: You need `IS NULL`, not `= NULL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use `Is null` and not = null

```
SELECT * 
FROM sd_menus a
LEFT JOIN sd_menu_items b
ON b.id_menu = a.id
LEFT JOIN `sd_menu_items_value_lang` c
ON c.item_id = b.id
WHERE a.name = 'mainNav'
AND (lang_id = 2 OR lang_id is  NULL)
```

Comment: I do not know why I didn't try that -.-. Worked like a charm. Thank you :-) Will mark your question as correct when stack allow me :)

Comment: The classic "never bothered to read a SQL book and learn it" thing - this is the stuff you overlook when you gather your knowledge from copy/paste and howtos which never explain fundamentals like sql null handling.

Answer (score 0):

Which table does `lang_id` belong to?

When doing `LEFT JOIN`, put the right side table's conditions in the `ON` clause to get true left join behavior. (When in `WHERE`, you need to add that `OR ... IS NULL`, otherwise you'll get regular inner join result.)

Assuming `lang_id` belongs to `sd_menu_items_value_lang`, adjust the query to:

```
SELECT * 
FROM sd_menus a
LEFT JOIN sd_menu_items b
ON b.id_menu = a.id
LEFT JOIN `sd_menu_items_value_lang` c
ON c.item_id = b.id AND c.lang_id = 2
WHERE a.name = 'mainNav'
```

It's good programming practice to always qualify columns, so people can know instantly which table a column comes from.